# Error en loaders en webpack

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, npm, webpack

Quiero montar un proyecto en **React** desde cero.

Me lanza el siguiente error:

```
ERROR in ./src/js/main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:4)

  3 | 
  4 | ReactDOM.render(
> 5 |     <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    |     ^
  6 |     document.getElementById('app')
  7 | );

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! reactjs-getting-started@0.1.0 build: `webpack --config webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-getting-started@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  }
}
```

**Webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'script.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use:{
                loader: "babel-loader",
            }
        }]
    }
};


import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React utiliza una extensión sobre JavaScript llamada [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) que permite definir etiquetas similares a HTML.
Para trabajar con estos scripts se requiere transformar el código.

En tu `webpack.config.js` tienes asociado el `babel-loader` para los archivos `.js`. Además, debes incluir un plugin para [transformar JSX](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx) o un Babel [preset para react](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) (que incluye el plugin anterior y otros de utilidad) en la configuración del *loader*.

Ejemplo usando el `babel-loader` con el `preset-react` para trabajar con script que incluyen sintaxis JSX. Se incluye además el `babel-preset-env` para transpilar la versión de JavaScript.

Debes incluir en tu proyecto un archivo [`.babelrc`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) para configurar el `babel-loader`:

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["babel-preset-env", "babel-preset-react"]
}
```

Paquetes de [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) requeridos como **devDependencies**:

- `babel-core`
- `babel-loader`
- `babel-preset-env`
- `babel-preset-react`

---

Hace poco respondí sobre un problema similar dónde se requería un *loader* apropiado para manejar el fichero *jsx*. Leer [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49547672/7248949).

También puedes revisar las configuraciones de [webpack-4](/questions/tagged/webpack-4) en este proyecto [Webpack-Demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) que utiliza [react](/questions/tagged/react).
Espero que sea de utilidad.